# How to read from 2 locales translation from 2 different folders in Nuxt 3 application using intlify?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

I have a Nuxt 3 or Nuxt.js application with the following folder structure:

```
root
 ┣ commons
 ┗ project1
 ┗ project2
```

I have a page in `project1` from which I can navigate to a page in `project2`. While navigating from project1 to project2 the page contents from project2/locales are not loaded. All the contents and components from `project2` are loading fine but the words and button text do not appear as it is unable to read `locales` content.

Even If I add the reference to it it's not working fine and still displays the respective variable name instead of the value mentioned in locales/en.

project1/nuxt.config.js

```
  intlify: [
    {
      localeDir: "locales",
      vueI18n: {
        locale: "en",
      },
    },
    {
      localeDir: "../project2/locales",
      vueI18n: {
        locale: "en",
      },
    },
  ],
```

`Project1` locales work fine but `project2/locales` are not loaded. However, when I run a `project2` independently everything works fine. but when I am trying to access `project2` from `project1` I get the error and locales are not loaded.

Can someone please let me know how can I make the `@intlify/nuxt3` to read from 2 different folders and achieve this?